# MySQL started performing ~2 times slower after upgrading Ubuntu from 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: server, upgrade, 20.04, mysql, 19.04

I have an Ubuntu Server where the main app running is MySQL Server v8

About a week ago I upgraded Ubuntu from 19.04 to 20.04 and since then the performance of my database has drastically fallen. Nothing helps, no parameters or something. It just works like 2 times slower. All of operations.

It's impossible to restore all back to 19.04 because it's EOL already. That's why I'm looking for other ways.

My server has 64GB RAM and 2 SSD's merged into RAID0.

My mysql config (it's optimised for very small amount of super heavy threads):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=40G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=10G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
sync_binlog=0
innodb_log_file_size=10G
max_heap_table_size=1G
tmp_table_size=1G
innodb_deadlock_detect=0
transaction_isolation='READ-UNCOMMITTED'
sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'
```

Any ideas what to check? Where should I dig into? Maybe it's some kernel issue? And the only way is to downgrade to 18.04 which LTS as well?

Comment: I found out that I have kernel version `5.4.0-53-generic` while the newest stable one at the moment is `5.9.9`. Is it worth updating the kernel? And is it safe at all?

Comment: I doubt it relates to the kernel (and 5.8 will be the next 20.04.2 kernel; if you go to a *testing* or non-Ubuntu-supported kernel you take on security patching yourself).  I'd also suggest not skipping releases in future. Did you verify no changes were skipped in the 19.10 release you skipped for your used programs (your upgrade path was outside of the QA-testing path, so checks & any config changes done by 19.10 were on you). The only *testing* performed on skipped releases is *automated* package issues.

Comment: @guiverc as I remember I first upgraded to 19.10 and then to 20.04 so I didn't skip anything. Probably the issue is that MySQL automatically updated from 8.0.19 to 8.0.22. But I'm struggling to find a way how to downgrade MySQL now.

Comment: I didn't find the actual reason. Perhaps something happened to SSD's. I bought another server, performed fresh install, transferred all data and it started to work fine.